# ChartPanel in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

i'm trying to add a ChartPanel in a JscrollPane and make the horizontal scrollbar visible only when needed. When there are too many columns in the chart, i want its panel to be more wide than the frame and make the horizontal scrollbar visible. I also want to have a minimum gap between the bars in my chart. I post my code, without scrollpane and without the minimum gap between bars. So my questions are:
how to set a precise gap between bars?
how to make visible an horizontal scroll when there are too many bars to represent on the frame width?

```
package view;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

public class StatisticsPanel extends AbstractCenterPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final ChartPanel chartPanel;

public StatisticsPanel(final Map<Calendar, Integer> cashMap) {
    super();

    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.ITALY);
    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    for (Entry<Calendar, Integer> e : cashMap.entrySet()) {
        dataset.setValue(e.getValue(), "Incasso", df.format(e.getKey().getTime()));
    }
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Andamento degli incassi", "Data", "Incasso (€)", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    this.chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

    final SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);

    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, this.chartPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, this.chartPanel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, this.chartPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, this.chartPanel, 350, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    this.add(this.chartPanel);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't add the chartPanel directly but wrap in a JScrollPane and add the JScrollPane instead.

Comment: @StanislaV I already tried. It doesn't work. The chartPanel doesn't become more wide.

Comment: Have you tried to call setPreferredSize of the chartPanel  specifiying desired width?

Comment: Alos consider a [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html).

Comment: @trashgod how does it work? Can you post a demo?

Comment: You might try the sample/demo, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).